# Adjusting layout of multiple Plotly (R) subplots programmatically

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am given a plotly object containing n subplots and I want to add a rangeslider to it. I do so using the code

```
p<- layout(p, xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(type = "date")))
```

However, I need to retain the ability to rescale the y axis on all the subplots. I know I can do so by again changing the layout in the following way:

```
p<- layout(p,
            yaxis = list(fixedrange = F),
            yaxis2 = list(fixedrange = F),
            yaxis3 = list(fixedrange = F),
             ...)
```

However, since the number of plots changes, I need a programmatic way of doing that. Note that the plotly object is generated using ggplotly, and as such I don't have access to the individual subplots to pass the layout options there.

I tried passing a list to layout, but it doesn't seem to produce the right result:

```
layoutlist <- list(yaxis = list(fixedrange = F), yaxis2 = list(fixedrange = F), yaxis3 = list(fixedrange = F), ...)
p<- layout(p, layoutlist)
```

does not return an error but also doesn't apply the layout options properly.

I also tried using unquoting (!!) to solve the issue but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is some sample code for replication:

(This part can't change)

```
subplots_list <- list()
for(i in 1:5){
  subplots_list[[i]] <- plot_ly()
}
p<- subplot(subplots_list, nrows = 5, shareX = T)
```

Expected result

```
p<- p %>% layout(xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(type = "date")))
p<- p %>% layout(
               yaxis = list(fixedrange = F),
               yaxis2 = list(fixedrange = F),
               yaxis3 = list(fixedrange = F),
               yaxis4 = list(fixedrange = F),
               yaxis5 = list(fixedrange = F)
               )
```

Thanks in advance for your help.